# How to select specific elements with certain attributes using AND in XPath?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I wan to select all elements in the same tree if the element name is [x or y or z] and have a defined attributes. The example which is working in PHP is:

```
xpath = "//*[name()='x' or name()='y' or name()='z'][descendant::w[@attrib][@attrib2='".$variable."']]";
```

So I was trying to write its equivalent in python 2.7:

```
xpath = "[//*[//x or //y or //z][descendant::w[@attrib][@attrib2='".{0}."']]".format(variable)
```

But it doesn't work for me. Actually I couldn't find out why the php code uses name() ? Can I and should I do the same in python?

Comment: @Epodax I removed php tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `name()='foo'` I would rather use `self::foo`. The following XPath should be equivalent to your first XPath :

```
xpath = '''//*[self::x or self::y or self::z]
              [descendant::w[@attrib and @attrib2='{0}']]
        '''.format(variable)
```